# What is the meaning and purpose of setences of the form "....cannot....without..."? How about other similiar forms such as "can" and "with"?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am not familiar with the thinking behind terminology of mathematics.

So I keep trying to improve on that.

I currently teach myself to write proofs by reading a textbook.

This book says

> We will say that an argument is valid if the premises cannot all be true without
> the conclusion being true as well.

Does the logical form of a valid argument mean ¬(P$\land$¬C) ?

How about others? Are they correct or meaningful?

Such as

**1**

> The premises `cannot` all be true **with** the conclusion being `true`.
>
> > ¬(P$\land$C)

**2**

> The premises `cannot` all be true `without` the conclusion being `true`.
>
> > ¬(P$\land$¬C)

**3**

> The premises `cannot` all be true **with** the conclusion being **false**.
>
> > ¬(P$\land$¬C)

**4**

> The premises `cannot` all be true `without` the conclusion being **false**.
>
> > ¬(P$\land$¬(¬C))

**5**

> The premises **can** all be true **with** the conclusion being `true`.
>
> > P$\land$C

**6**

> The premises **can** all be true `without` the conclusion being `ture`.
>
> > (P$\land$¬C)

**7**

> The premises **can** all be true **with** the conclusion being **false**.
>
> > P$\land$¬C

**8**

> The premises **can** all be true `without` the conclusion being **false**.
>
> > P$\land$¬(¬C)

As above there is only the second sentence which is mentioned in the book.

Other seven senteces are made by me out of curiosity.

Comment: The sentence in the book is, indeed, $\neg(P\wedge\neg C)$. The others are all meaningful, but the only ones that correctly describe the validity of arguments are the ones that are logically equivalent to $\neg(P\wedge\neg C)$.

Comment: Do you think all other 7 logic forms match the meaning of corresponding sentences?

Comment: "cannot" says something can't happen. "can" says something might, or might not, happen. It doesn't say something *must* happen. If I had to interpret, say, $P\wedge C$, I'd interpret it as "premises and conclusion *are* true," not as "premises *may* be true when conclusion is true."

Comment: It sounds great. So do you suggest that the second half of the logic forms, namely sentences #5-#8, ARE not accurate? I am not familiar with the thinking behind terminology of mathematics. Thanks, STILL. Professor, your comments are valuable to me.

Comment: For what it's worth, in my opinion the sentence you are having difficulty with should have been written in a more straightforward way, such as -- *For us, an argument is valid means: if all the premises are true, then the conclusion is true.* The textbook's sentence mixes an "if ... then" construction (which is actually "if and only if") at the sentence level (i.e. if something is the case, then we say the argument is valid) with an implied "if ... then" construction in the definition of "valid", along with some confusing negation (double-negation?) constructions.

Comment: To continue, this is not something that is associated with mathematical writing, but rather something that is associated with writing that was not properly edited. The author (or a copyeditor) should have noticed at the proofing/editing stage, and probably before (such as moments after first writing the sentence, when looking it over), that the cognitive task in parsing the sentence as intended is far more difficult than the concept being explained. I'm reminded of Linderholm's book [**Mathematics Made Difficult**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_Made_Difficult).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Hehe

Comment: By the way, the author is Daniel J. Velleman whose PhD advisor was Mary Rudin. Ms. Rudin is the wife of Walter Rudin.  Mr. Rudin is the author of some famous textbooks on analysis. Though a bit interesting in my view.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro A similar case I can come up with. As you mentioned, in some books on mathematical logic the definition such as "p implies q" is false if and only if "p is true and q is false", namely the conditional connective, is provided EXPLICITLY. Other books just give an explanation instead, but the definition such as logical AND connective is provided explicitly in these books. I don't know the reason. But similar approaches occur. For example some notion which is seen as a theorem by an author is just a definition by another author. I hope that I convey the message I intend to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > We will say that an argument is valid if the premises cannot all be true without the conclusion being true as well.
>
> Does the logical form of a valid argument mean ¬(P$\land$¬C) ?

Yes, since the original verbal sentence is rephrased as "it cannot be the case that the premises are all true in conjunction with the conclusion not being true".

Similarly, Translations 1-4 are all meaningful and accurate.

On the other hand, Translations 5-8 are meaningful but inaccurate: for example, Translation 5 asserts that the premises and conclusion are all true, whereas the original verbal sentence allows for a false premise in conjunction with a true conclusion.

> > **5.** The premises **can** all be true **with** the conclusion being `true`.
>
> P$\land$C

Comment: Wow! you are alway of assistance, as usual. I am still taking baby steps forward.

Comment: Put it simply. The original verbal sentence does not exclude the case where a false premice and a true conlcusion. What a fantastic discusion I need! Appreciate it.

Comment: You remind me again for upvoting. My first language in not English, I am asian. But I enjoy thinking in English while solving mathematical problems.

Comment: @StatsCruncher Based on our previous exchanges about terminologies and logic, I wouldn't have guessed that English isn't your first language! Thanks again for your enthusiasim, and, to repeat my deleted comment, these 8 exercises are less about mathematics and more about interpreting, or even disambiguating, natural language (English).

Comment: @StatsCruncher Speaking of doing mathematics in English, it just occurred to me that (East?) Asian languages are known to be higher-context languages than English, yet appear to many to be more literal/logical when it comes to elementary mathematics (or perhaps just counting).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your personal experience. Mandarin is quite different from East Asian languages such as Korean and Japanese. For me, when it comes to advanced mathematics, I prefer English to Mandarin. At least thinking and writing proofs in English is more logical than in Mandarin beyond high school maths.

Comment: @StatsCruncher It's actually not from experience, else I'd have more to say about the topic, hehe.

Comment: Because of English I have an opportunity to know "Federico Ardila's axioms". I am supprised at and encouraged by the axioms